# Real Analysis Toolkit?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, soft-question, big-list

Is there a good collection of common tools and equations used to solve analysis/calculus problems? I am quite good at proving theorems, but I struggle at equation manipulation (finding limits, or solving inequalities etc).

Thank you!

Comment: That's far too broad for a question. There are a very large number of techniques. There's a reason it usually is a many year course of study.

Comment: Welcome to mathematics.

Comment: May not be exactly what was asked for, but http://www.lkozma.net/inequalities_cheat_sheet/ineq.pdf is a great list of common inequalities. It is well presented and I find myself inevitably going back to it when trying to solve an inequality.

Comment: The triangle inequality goes a long way

Comment: Here is a toolkit for real analysis https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/245a-problem-solving-strategies/

Comment: there is a lot of tricks and theorems that you will learn with the time. But Im not aware of a "collection" of general tricks/theorems. Take a look at books of mathematical competitions or books of problem solving strategies to learn more "tricks"

Comment: @Systems: I am not looking for Software tools.        I know the Terry Tao blog post, but I need something more tangible. The list of inequalities is a step in the right direction.

Comment: Work exercises. Work exercises. And please do not forget to work exercises.